# Determinant of $ 3\times 3$ matrix by using gauss

Tags: matrices, determinant, gaussian-elimination

I am trying to calculate the determinant of the following matrix by performing Gaussian elimination. I know that the determinant is $1$ but I get the wrong result.

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
 2 & 3 & -4 
  \end{bmatrix}

$r_2-r_1$ gives:

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 \\
 2 & 3 & -4 
  \end{bmatrix}

$r_3-2r_1$ gives:

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 1 & -6 
  \end{bmatrix}

Swap $r_2$ and $r_3$

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & -6 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 
  \end{bmatrix}

Determinant$= 1.1.(-1) = -1$ which is wrong.

Comment: After ${r}_{2}-{r}_{1}$ you have $\text{det} = \left|\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\
2&3
\end{array}\right|$. Why don't you use this?

Comment: Yes , you are right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you swap rows $r_2$ and $r_3$, you introduce a negative one in the determinant, hence the determinent is $-(-1)=1$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $ \det \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & -6 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 
  \end{bmatrix}= - \det \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 1 & -6 
  \end{bmatrix}$,

since you swapped $r_2 $ and $r_3$.